# How can I make a middle letter lowercase in php

Tags: php

I would like to do the following:

I have a set of letters like `AGG` or `DOH`, I would like to set only the middle of the string to be lowercase such as this: `AgG` or `DoH`.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What if the word length is even? ex: `AGGH`?

Comment: You can set any specific character to lowercase by using `$string[2] = strtolower($string[2]);` (`2` would be the index, hence the 3rd character). Then it's simply a job for you to do some math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is always 3 characters:

```
$test = 'AOC';
$test[1] = strtolower($test[1]);
```

If you need it for more than 3 no need to run a loop:

```
$test = 'AOCA';
$test = ucfirst(strtolower($test));
$test[(strlen($test)-1)] = strtoupper($test[(strlen($test)-1)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic solution:

```
$test = 'ASDFG';
for( $i=1 ; $i < (strlen($test)-1), $i++ ) {
    $test[$i] = strtolower($test[$i]); 
}
echo $test;
```

This would output

```
AsdfG
```

and works for strings greater then 3 positions.

Answer (score -1):

Check the bellow example making use of ucwords():

```
<?php
$foo = 'hello world!';
$foo = ucwords($foo);             // Hello World!

$bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
$bar = ucwords($bar);             // HELLO WORLD!
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar)); // Hello World!
?>
```

ucwords(strtolower($bar)); is what I think you want!